# Problem with deleting words from text

Tags: string-manipulation, text

The task I need to do is to import a text book from here http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/36/pg36.txt, then drop the last 20000 words from it and determine how many times the remaining words occur.

```
text = Drop[Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/36/pg36.txt", "Words"], -20000];

wordcounts = WordCounts[text];

top30 = Take[Transpose[{Keys@wordcounts, Values@wordcounts}], 30];
TableForm[top30, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Words", "Count"}}];
```

Why doesn't the above code work?

Comment: Look up `Drop[]`.

Comment: Will it work with words? Or is it just going to drop characters instead of words? Sorry I am asking, can't check it up right now.

Comment: ...maybe you should show the code you already have, so that we aren't left guessing.

Comment: `Drop[Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/36/pg36.txt", 
  "Words"], -20000]`?

Comment: `WordCounts` takes a single string as it 1st argument. You have given it a list of words. Since you already have a list, use `Counts`.

Comment: Thanks, it does work, now I need to figure out what will be the simple way to get rid of the punctuation like dots and other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
text = Drop[Import["http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/36/pg36.txt", "Words"], -20000];
Length@text
```

> 42 996